# How do I extract a single digit from a string of digits?

Tags: java, string

Example:

```
String number = "1234567890123456";
```

How do I store the second to last digit by itself in a int type variable?

Detailed:

```
for (int i = number.length()-2; i>-1; i-=2)
    int x = (Extract the  number) at i;
```

How do I do this?

Here's the code:

```
package creditcard;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Card {

    //Declarations
    private String cardNumber;
    private boolean test = false;
    private String cardType = "Unknown";

    public Card(){
        cardNumber = "0";
    }//end Default Constructor

    public Card(String input){
        cardNumber = input;
    }//end Constructor

    //
    public void typeMatcher(){
        if (cardNumber.startsWith("37"))
            cardType = "American Express";
        if (cardNumber.startsWith("4"))
            cardType = "Visa";
        if (cardNumber.startsWith("5"))
            cardType = "Mastercard";
        if (cardNumber.startsWith("6"))
            cardType = "Discover";
    }//end typeMatcher

    // Returns true if card number is Valid.
    public boolean isValid(String cardNumber){
        if (cardNumber.length() > 12 && cardNumber.length() < 17)
            if((sumOfDoubleEvenPlace(cardNumber)+sumOfOddPlace(cardNumber))/10==0)
                test = true;
        return test;
    }//end isValid

    // Get result from Step 2.
    public int sumOfDoubleEvenPlace(String cardNumber){
        int sum = 0;
        int num = 0;
        for (int i = cardNumber.length()-2; i>-1; i-=2){
            num = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.substring(i,i+1));
            if (num<10)
                sum+=(num*2);
            else
                sum+=getDigit(num);
        }//end for
        System.out.println(sum);
        return sum;
    }//end SumOfDoubleEvenPlace

    // Return this number if it is a single digit
    // Otherwise return the sum of the two digits.
    public int getDigit (int num){
        int no1 = num/10;
        int no2 = num%10;
        return no1+no2;
    }//end getDigit

    // Returns sum of odd place digits in number.
    public int sumOfOddPlace(String cardNumber){
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = cardNumber.length()-1; i>-1; i-=2)
            sum += Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.substring(i,i));
        System.out.println(sum);
        return sum;
    }//end sumOfOddPlace

    public void writeToFile(){
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("G:\\Output.txt",true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            if (isValid(cardNumber)){
                bw.write(cardNumber+" is a valid "+cardType+" card.");
                bw.newLine();
            }//end if
            else{
                bw.write(cardNumber+" is an invalid "+cardType+" card.");
                bw.newLine();
            }//end else
            bw.close();
            System.out.println("Success");
        }//end try

        catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }//end catch

    }//end outputToFile

}//end Card
```

The goal is to check if a credit card number is valid (School project)

Answer (score 2):

Just [substring](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)/[charAt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) the digit(s) that you want and parse it...

```
int d = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(start, start+1))
```

Comment: This is my error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: @kid: eh, I've used this before so I *know* it works; maybe you could tell us what it does that you don't want it to?

Comment: But it is not empty. I have print statements that show y string is not, for double checking.

Comment: @Kid: The error message even says it's an empty string, so you can print as many lines of debug code as you want. I suppose you're passing the wrong values into `substring`.

Comment: isn't it a bit mean to be voting down answers you don't happen to "like"?

Comment: @Kid: Add that output to your question please.

Comment: @Renan: looking at his profile, Kid can't downvote yet so someone else went on a vote-a-thon.

Comment: If I understand substring parameters (i, i+1) means start at i and end at the spot before i+1, which is i.

Comment: @Kid, try my updated answer please; I might have got the second param wrong

Comment: @Kid Programmer your friend here is the debug statement. why not print out the result of the substring call, see what you get, then adjust as necessary.

Comment: Okay, well apparently it suddenly works, The code I linked to was a previous version and I guess it finally works. Idk. But thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
int x = number.charAt(i) - '0'
```

`Integer.parseInt` is overkill here.

Answer (score 0):

Your substring code in method **sumOfOddPlace** has a flaw:

```
  sum += Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.substring(i,i));
```

that should be

```
  sum += Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.substring(i,i+1));
```

This is probably the cause of your format exception.

Answer (score -1):

There's a little method called "charAt()" that'll do what you want.

```
 char c = someString.charAt(someString.length - 2);
```

Then you need to convert the character to an integer.

Pick @Andrew White's answer because that makes the integer conversion easier. You can do it from a char, but it's a little icky (well not to me because I'm a C programmer at heart).

Comment: I'm sick of answering Java questions here. The pedantic jerk level is just too high.

Comment: Amen. It's sickening sometimes.

Comment: The character of '0' has a numeric value of 48 iirc. That's probably where the downvote came from.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the second to last:

```
if (number.length() >= 2) {
    int myNumber = number.charAt(number.length() - 2) - '0';
}
```

Or for your loop:

```
for (int i = number.length()-2; i>-1; i-=2)
    int x = number.charAt(i) - '0';
```

Comment: The OP said DIGIT, as such, `charAt` is a lot more performant than an expensive integer parse operation. Obviously, once we're dealing with more than one digit, using the proper Integer methods would be preferable.

Comment: The issue is that the x in this scenario is an int that doesn't equal the char at that point, instead it equals the value of the unicode, I think. Kid Programmer is slang for newbie.

Comment: That's why there's the `- '0'`. Maybe you should try the code first before voting it down?

Comment: @EboMike: just a preference but I avoid - '0' unless this is super critical code since that is just harder to read. (but I didn't down vote the world to express that:) )

Comment: @Andrew: I'm around "optimized C++ code" too much, so this is still above my threshold where I would call something cryptic :) I'm all for making code readable and easy to understand when performance is not an issue, although my inner demon simply wouldn't allow me to create a substring and parse it to handle a single digit. But yeah, `Integer.parseInt` is as clear as it gets when you want to express a string-to-int conversion.

Comment: @Andrew: I know :) It's like a magic fairy, sprinkling downvoting dust on all of us! I still think there should be mandatory comments when downvoting, but that's been discussed to death at this point.